# What's the difference between big O and big Omega?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Big Omega is supposed to be the opposite of Big O, but they can always have the same value, because by definition Big O means:

```
g(x) so that cg(x) is bigger or equal to f(x)
```

and Big Omega means

`g(x) so that cg(x) is smaller or equal to f(x)`

the only thing that changes is the value of c, if the value of c is an arbitrary value (a value that we choose to meet inequality), then Big Omega and Big O will be the same. So what's the point of those two? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: `c` is not allowed to vary with `x`. Given `f` and `g`, there must be a particular `c` that makes the inequality true for all sufficiently large `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Big O is bounded above by (up to constant factor) asymptotically while Big Omega is bounded below by (up to constant factor) asymptotically.

Mathematically speaking, f(x) = O(g(x)) (big-oh) means that the growth rate of f(x) is asymptotically less than or equal to to the growth rate of g(x).

f(x) = Ω(g(x)) (big-omega) means that the growth rate of f(x) is asymptotically greater than or equal to the growth rate of g(x)

See the Wiki reference below:

[Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you want to prove an upper bound (Big Oh), some other times you want to prove a lower bound (Big Omega).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation:

[image: Family of Bachmann–Landau notations]

Answer (score -1):

You're correct when you assert that such a g exists, but that doesn't mean it's known.

In addition to talking about the complexity of algorithms you can also talk about the complexity of *problems*.

It's known that [multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lower_bounds) for example is Ω(n) and O(n log(n) log(log(n))) in the number of bits, but a precise characterization (denoted by Θ) is unknown. It's the same story with [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) and [NP problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) in general which is what the whole P versus NP thing is about.

Furthermore there are apparently [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Optimal_algorithm) and ones proven to be optimal no less whose complexity is unknown. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Erel_Segal/Optimal_algorithms_with_unknown_runtime_complexity